# imagepng works on xampp but not on server

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, folder-permissions

I have this small code to generate profile images with random background color and first letter of name as text over it. I've been using this code for years and it still works fine on xampp and many other sites but in one praticular case its not working on the server.

The image is not being saved. I've checked all directories have 755 permissions. GD is installed and there are no errors in the apache log.

```
<?php
$name = 'Vipul Kapoor';
$id = 905;
$location = '';

$words = explode(" ", $name);
$countWords = count($words);
if($countWords >= 2){
    $firstChars =  $words[0][0].$words[$countWords-1][0];
}else{
    $firstChars = "";
    foreach ($words as $w)
    {
        $firstChars .= $w[0];
    }
}
$alphaCount = strlen($firstChars);
$font = 'fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf';
$imgName = $id.'-default.png';
$im = imagecreate(215, 215);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, mt_rand(0, 200), mt_rand(0, 200), mt_rand(0, 200));
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
if($alphaCount == 1)  { imagettftext($im, 60, 0, 80, 132, $text_color, $font, $firstChars); }
if($alphaCount == 2)  { imagettftext($im, 50, 0, 65, 132, $text_color, $font, $firstChars); }
if($location == ''){
    imagepng($im, 'images/profile/'.$imgName);
}else{
    imagepng($im, 'admin/img/avatar/'.$imgName);
}
imagedestroy($im);
```

I've seen similar questions and their solutions didn't help. How do I diagnose the problem?

Edit: Its not just image files but php can't create any files at all. Other codes that generate csv files are also failing. It seems php just can not write files on this server. Its no permission problem I'm sure of it so there's some configuration issue. How should I get to the root of the problem?

Comment: Is this a Windows or Linux webserver?

Comment: You need to give write access to your webserver process in the folder you want to do anything in.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Can you share a link or describe in detail about how to give write access?

Comment: try 777 instead of 755. This is not the best use of it but at least will validate that it's "possible". Then work you way back and see where the permissions are revoked

Comment: Have you tried to use a higher level of error reporting and logging to see where exactly your script stops executing?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can get the access of the folder by. Then the username will get the ownership of that folder.

```
sudo chown -R <username> /var/www
```

Option 2: you can cange the folder permissions by

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwX /var/www
```

Option 3: Or you can give a group access to the folder

```
sudo groupadd www
sudo useradd -g <username> www
sudo chown -R :www /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Documentation: You can read more about this in their serverguide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf

Comment: I'm getting a 'Operation not permitted' error even with `sudo`. username I'm using is 'www-data'

Comment: did you log in with `su`?

Comment: I logged in as root user